# Cassandra Thrift adding dynamic row with DateType Comparator

Tags: nosql, cassandra, thrift

I have the following column family:

```
CREATE COLUMN FAMILY messages with comparator=DateType and key_validation_class=UTF8Type and default_validation_class=UTF8Type;
```

now I'm using Cassandra Thrift to store new Data:

```
 TTransport tr = this.dataSource.getConnection();
         TProtocol proto = new TBinaryProtocol(tr);      
         Cassandra.Client client = new Cassandra.Client(proto);
         long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            client.set_keyspace("myTestSPace");
             ColumnParent parent = new ColumnParent("messages");
             Column messageColumn = new Column();
             String time = String.valueOf(timestamp);        
             messageColumn.setName(time.getBytes());
             messageColumn.setValue(toByteBuffer(msg.getText));
             messageColumn.setTimestamp(timestamp);
             client.insert(toByteBuffer(msg.getAuthor()), parent, messageColumn, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
```

but I'm getting exception:

```
InvalidRequestException(why:Expected 8 or 0 byte long for date (16))
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$insert_result.read(Cassandra.java:15198)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_insert(Cassandra.java:858)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.insert(Cassandra.java:830)
    at com.vanilla.cassandra.DaoService.addMessage(DaoService.java:57)
```

How to do it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're using the raw Thrift interface.  For reasons like the one you've encountered and many, many more, I strongly suggest that you use an existing high-level client like [Hector](https://github.com/hector-client/hector), [Astyanax](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax), or a CQL client.

The root cause of your issue is that you have to pack different datatypes into a binary format. The higher level clients manage this automatically.